# ExtJS moving custom validations to external files

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, external

Some of my validations are repeated in various views. I'd like to move them to external files to facilitate reuse. As an example, I'd like to be able to use something like this:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, Ext.custom.validations.Oib);
```

instead of applying validations to VTypes singleton like this:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    oib: function(val, field) {
        oib = val.toString();
        if (oib.length != 11) return false;
        var b = parseInt(oib, 10);
        if (isNaN(b)) return false;
        var a = 10;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a = a + parseInt(oib.substr(i, 1), 10);
        a = a % 10;
        if (a == 0) a = 10;
        a *= 2;
        a = a % 11;
        }
        var control = 11 - a;
        if (control == 10) control = 0;
        return control == parseInt(oib.substr(10, 1));
    },
    oibText: 'Wrong oib.',
    oibMask: /[\d]/i
});
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you add validations into singleton `Ext.form.field.VTypes` they will be accessible everywhere. No? What's the problem then?

Comment: I guess that's true, but I have a specific situation where I have to have separate html pages, each calling ExtJS scripts. That's why I would want to put the validations in a separate file, to facilitate reuse.

Comment: Create a common .js file that get included into every page. What's the problem?

Comment: I'd like to load the appropriate validation with Ext.require, but I'm not sure how to do that for validations.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed with approximately this:

Put my files in

```
/ext4/custom
```

First define the path to my external files.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths : {
    'custom' : '/ext4/custom'
    }
});
```

Require the file

```
Ext.require([ 'Ext.*', 'custom.validations.Oib' ]);
```

Finally, apply the validation to singleton:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, Ext.create('custom.validations.Oib'));
```